# Where to get Phượng coffee?

Tags: ground-coffee, vietnam

Where in Europe can one buy the excellent Vietnamese coffee of the Phượng brand which is shown in the photo?

[image: Package of Phượng coffee]

Comment: They have a website. You could contact the company.

Answer (score 1):

If you live in or near a major city any large Asian supermarket should carry it or a substitutes to try.  In San Diego, Ranch 99 is one such market.